# How to detect if a longer chain of commands in cron fails?

Tags: cron

I want to create a crontab wrapper in python that logs if a crontab entry fails. It should be useable like this:

```
0 * * * * cronwrapper -c "some_command | some_other_command & third_command 2>/dev/null && fourth_command"
```

The logging part is quite easy and already done. However, I don't know how I can reliably detect if any one command in the pipe or the logical-and or the forking fails.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to reliably detect the exit code of all commands in the example above.

Why can't you add all 4 commands inside a small bash script and use:

```
0 * * * * cronwrapper -c "script.sh"
```

This way you'll be able to better handle any errors inside your script

You may also want to enable bash `pipefail` for `some_command | some_other_command`

See the difference in exit codes below for the same pipeline

```
$ set -o | grep pipefail
pipefail        off
$ ls bla &> /dev/null | echo aa
aa
$ echo $?
0

$ set -o pipefail
$ set -o | grep pipefail
pipefail        on
$ ls bla &> /dev/null | echo aa
aa
$ echo $?
1
```